# Why document.title doesn't work for SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, w3c

I created simple SVG document and open it in Chrome and FF

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="4in" height="3in">
  <g>
    <title>Company sales by region</title>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Why does document.title return ""?

According to standard https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#dom-tree-accessors

> document . title [ = value ]
>   Returns the document’s title, as given by the title element for HTML and as given by the SVG title element for SVG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `document.title` on this instead:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="4in" height="3in">
  <title>Company sales by region</title>
</svg>
```

The [spec says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-tree-accessors:document-element-2):

> If the document element is an SVG `svg` element, then let *value* be the child text content of the first SVG `title` element **that is a child of the document element**.

So the reason `document.title` returns `""` for the snippet in the question is that in that snippet the `title` element isn’t a child of the document element (the `svg` element).

Answer (score 2):

To display a hint message when you hover over an `svg` element, you need to wrap it with group tags.
You have group tags `<g>` but inside is empty.

*See the example below where the prompt will be displayed:*

```html
<svg  width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<g id="titleRect">
<title> This is a green square </title>
<rect id="rect1" x="10" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="yellowgreen" /> 
</g>

<g id="titleCircle">
<title> This is a purple circle.  </title>
<circle id="circle1" cx="200" cy="150" r="50"  fill="purple" /> 
</g>
</svg>
```

**Multi-line tooltip**

To get a multi-line tooltip, you must use a line break inside the `<title>` tags

```css
html, body, svg {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100vmin;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-4 -4 8 8">
  <g>
    <title>Multiline
the tooltip is
very easy!</title>
    <circle r="4" fill="purple" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**The second way to get a multiline tooltip**

This method uses nested tags `<title>`

```
<title> 
       <title>   &#10697;   Atom properties </title>
       <title> &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135; </title>
       <title> Name: oxygen </title>
       <title> Atomic mass (molar mass) :15,99903 </title>
       <title> Atomic radius    60 (48) пм  </title> 
       <title> &#10697; Chemical properties  </title>
<title>
```

Hover cursor the center circle and see a multiline tooltip.

```css
.container {
width:40%;
height:40%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-52 -53 100 100" stroke-width="2">
 
 <g fill="none">
   <g> 
     <title> Orbit of the first atom  </title> 
    <ellipse fill="#F0F0F0" stroke="#66899a" rx="6" ry="44" />
   </g>  
       <g>     
        <ellipse fill="#F0F0F0" stroke="#e1d85d" rx="6" ry="44"  transform="rotate(-66)"/>
    <title> Orbit of the second atom  </title> 
  </g>  
  <g> 
      <ellipse fill="#F0F0F0" stroke="#80a3cf" rx="6" ry="44" transform="rotate(66)"/>
       <title> Orbit of the third atom  </title> 
  </g>   
  
    
   <circle  stroke="#4b541f" r="44"/> 
   

 </g> 
 <g fill="#66899a" stroke="white">
   <g>   
     <title> 
    <title>   &#10697;   Atom properties </title>
    <title> &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135; </title>
    <title> Name: oxygen </title>
    <title> Atomic mass (molar mass) :15,99903 </title>
    <title> Atomic radius 60 (48) пм  </title> 
    <title> &#10697; Chemical properties  </title>
     <title> &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135; </title>
    <title> Covalent radius 73 пм </title>
    <title> Ion radius 132 (-2e) пм </title>
    <title> Electrode potential 0 </title>
    <title>&#10697;Thermodynamic properties of a simple substance </title>
     <title> &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135; </title>
    <title>Density (at n. At.) Gas: 1,42897 kg/m³ </title>
    <title>Melting temperature 54,8 К (-218,35 °C) </title>
    <title>Boiling temperature 90,19 К (-182,96 °C) </title>
    
  </title>
     <circle fill="#80a3cf" r="13"/>
      
    </g>
  
 <g>
    <title>First atom</title>   
     <circle cy="-44" r="9"/>
 </g> 
   <g>
     <title>Second atom</title>
     <circle cx="40" cy="18" r="9"/>
   </g>
      <g>
         <title>Third atom</title> 
         <circle cx="-40" cy="18" r="9"/>
     </g> 
   
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @aroslav Baranov See another answer. Maybe useful.

Comment: Multiline tooltip! very interesting